# Removed an internal hard drive with windows and ubuntu dual boot; can only see windows partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, hard-drive

I removed the hard drive of a laptop with Ubuntu and Windows on two partitions and put it into an enclosure. On plugging it into a windows PC, I only see my windows partition. I am unable to plug it into an ubuntu PC as I do not have access to one.

Is there a solution that will allow me to acess both partitions? Thanks.

Comment: What was the filesystem of the Ubuntu partition and have you got a driver for it on Windows? If not you can boot a live CD/Live USB or a Linux distro on your computer. You'll be able to access your Linux partition and the local disk drive.

Comment: Open the disk management in Windows, it will probably list a partition it can't read since Linux was most likely not using NTFS or FAT